# Can $xy$ and $yx$ lie in different connected components of the group of invertible elements of an algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

What is  an example of  a  Banach or $C^{*}$ algebra $A$ which has two invertible elements $x, y$ such that $xy$ can not be connected to $yx$ in $G(A)$, the space of invertible elements of $A$.

A possible (weak) motivation for this question is that $K_{1}(A)$  is  an Abelian group.

Another motivation: Put  $F_{2}=$Free group on 2 generators $x,y$. then in the reduced $C^{*}-$algebra $C_{r}^{*} F_{2}$, $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ lies in the same connected component as of the identity.

Comment: I think it suffices to consider $C^*(x,y)$ for some non-commuting invertible elements $x,y$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  I think some thing is missing in your comment. The invertyible group of finite dimensional algebras is connected.

Comment: then something is indeed missing; it seems I'm out of my depth.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom if $x$ and $y$ are hermitian and invertible, $\sigma(xy)=\overline{\sigma(yx)}$ but also $\sigma(xy)=\sigma(yx)$ so the spectrum is real. You can take a path from $xy$ to $i\mathbb{1}+xy$, then go to $i\mathbb{1}$, then to $i\mathbb{1}+yx$ while never being noninvertible.

Comment: @s.harp thanks for that

Comment: @s.harp  Does $A=\bar{A}$ imply that $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @AliTaghavi ah, of course not for sets, that was an obvious mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they can lie in different components. (Answer rewritten for clarity; conclusion the same.)

I'll give one example with a real Banach algebra and one with a complex $C^{\ast}$ algebra. Both rely on a result of [Samelson,H.,"Groups and spaces of loops, Comm.Math.Helv.,28,278-87 (1954)]

**Theorem (Samelson)** Define two maps $\lambda$ and $\rho: SU(2) \times SU(2) \to SU(2)$ by $\lambda(g,h)=gh$ and $\rho(g,h)=hg$. Then $\lambda$ and $\rho$ are not homotopic.

We will need to know that $\lambda$ and $\rho$ remain nonhomotopic if we embed $SU(2)$ into larger groups.

**Lemma** $\lambda$ and $\rho$ remain nonhomotopic if we view their target as the nonzero quaternions (embedding $SU(2)$ as the norm one quaternions.

**Proof** The map $q \mapsto q/|q|$ is a retraction from the nonzero quaternions onto $SU(2)$; any homotopy could be composed with this retraction to violate Samelson's result. $\square$

**Lemma** $\lambda$ and $\rho$ remain nonhomotopic if we view their target as $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

**Proof** For a $2 \times 2$ matrix $X$, write $X^{\ast}$ for the conjugate transpose. Then $X \mapsto \sqrt{X X^{\ast}}^{-1} X$ is a retraction from $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ onto $U(2)$, and $Y \mapsto Y \left( \begin{smallmatrix} \det(Y)^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ is a retraction from $U(2)$ onto $SU(2)$. $\square$.

---

Now let $X = SU(2) \times SU(2)$ and let $H$ be either the quaternions or $\mathrm{Mat}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{C})$. Consider the algebra $A$ of continuous functions $X \to H$, equipped with the sup norm. If $H=\mathrm{Mat}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{C})$, this is a $C^{\ast}$ algebra, using the standard $C^{\ast}$ structure on $\mathrm{Mat}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{C})$. Let $x$ and $y \in A$ be the first and second projections from $X$ to $SU(2)$, followed by the obvious embeddings $SU(2) \to H$.

An element of $A$ is a unit if and only if it is valued in nonzero quaternions (if $H$ is the quaternions) or valued in $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ (if $H$ is $\mathrm{Mat}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{C})$). So $xy$ and $yx$ han be joined by a path through units if and only if they give homotopic maps $X \to (\mathrm{nonzero quaternions})$ or $X \to GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ respectively -- which we showed they don't. $\square$

See these answers by [Eric Wofsey](https://mathoverflow.net/a/160293/297) and [Achim Krause](https://mathoverflow.net/a/160307/297) for more on the homotopy structure of maps $SU(2) \times SU(2) \to SU(2)$.

**UPDATE 2/29/16** A very similar example appears in a 1973 paper of Yuen ([Groups of Invertible Elements of Banach algebras](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183534295), Yuen, Bull of the AMS Volume 79, Number 1 (1973), 82-84 Example 2); she credits it to E. Fadell. Also, [Klaja and Ransford](http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.08109) give an intriguing example of a different kind of noncommutativity -- a Banach algebra with elements $a$ and $b$ such that $1-ab$ is in the connected component of the identity but $1-ba$ is not!

Comment: Are you talking about real Banach algebra?

Comment: Are there some example of complex Banach or C* algebras, with that property?

Comment: Yes, the quaternions considered as a real Banach algebra. Thoughts on the complex case added.

Comment: New version addresses the real and complex case in parallel. Yes, there are $C^{\ast}$ examples.

Comment: Thanks  very  much  for  your very interesting answer.